# How to solve the import-local-package problem: GOPATH is ignored, only GOROOT takes effects

Tags: go, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, gopath

I'm new in GO and has got stuck in environment configuration for hours.

I succeeded to run some test projects, but when I tried to import my custom local packages (say xxx),  the "go run" command failed, logging that:

```
*test/main/main.go:6:2: package test/xxx is not in GOROOT (/usr/local/go/src/test/xxx)*
```

It is strange that GOPATH seems to be ignored when importing local packages on my ubuntu computer.

go version is *go1.16.5 linux/amd64*

GOPATH is set using   *export GOPATH="$HOME/GoProjects"*

GOROOT is set using   *export GOPATH="/usr/local/go"*

GoMod is "on" using   *go env -w GO111MODULE=on*

After editing project's .go files, command *"go mod init"* and "go mod tidy" are typed in the root folder of the project ($GOPATH/src/test), and the project file structure looks like:

```
/src
  /.vscode
    -launch.json
  /gitbub.com
  /test
    /main
      -main.go     (here: import "test/xxx")
    /xxx
      -xxx.go      (here: package xxx)
    -go.mod        (almost empty - line 1: module test
                                   line 2: 
                                   line 3: go 1.16     )
```

What should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: It's sad, nothing changed.

Comment: Assuming (not clear from your post) this entire tree is under your $HOME/GoProjects. When using modules you don't want to put your project or its dependencies inside GOPATH. Mixing them only leads to problems.

Comment: Regardless of the details of the funcs, there seems no other difference. Your method is inspiring, and I have just tried my codes on my WIN10 system, and the codes succeed. Now we can say the problem should lie in some configurations or commands.

Comment: Do not name a module `test`. Some names are reserved. Especially all names without a dot. Name your module `my.test.naming-is-hard`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, stop worrying about `GOPATH`. That is old stuff, and you don't need to do it any more. Then, make a folder somewhere `test` (doesn't need to be anything to do with `GOPATH`, just put in current directory, or wherever you want). Then make `test/xxx`. Then make `test/xxx/xxx.go`:

```
package xxx

const X = 1
```

Then make folder `test/main`. Then make `test/main/main.go`:

```
package main
import "test/xxx"

func main() {
   println(xxx.X)
}
```

Then go back to `test`, and do `go mod init test`. Then go back to `test/main`,
and do `go build`. Done.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming (not clear from your post) this entire tree is under your `$HOME/GoProjects`. When using modules; don't put your project inside GOPATH as mixing both GOPATH and modules only leads to problems.

First, set `$GOPATH` to something like `$HOME/go` which you can use to `go get` various tools you want to use across projects (such as e.g. `dlv` debugger and so on) but **do not put your projects in there**.

When starting a new project put it **outside** `$GOPATH` to `$HOME/GoProjects/test` (you can retain project layout you have under `src` but you do not need `src` there):

```
GoProjects
  /test
    /main
      -main.go
    /xxx
      -xxx.go
```

In project directory (here `test`) run `go mod init NAME` where NAME is name of your module. Do not use just `test` but fully qualified name which will namespace your project to your "domain" (e.g. `github.com/yourusername/test`). That name will then be used when importing packages from your module. So in `main.go` you will import `xxx` package (needs to have `package xxx`) like this:

```golang
import "github.com/yourusername/test/xxx"
```

See more info about modules here: https://blog.golang.org/using-go-modules